# Datagridview give error ` index -1 does not have value`

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I am having a strange issue. After assigning list to DataSource. When I click on the grid, error appears `Index -1 does not have value`. 
No matter where i placed try and catch this error is not caught.

Below is the code of adding data to list and assigning to the DataSource.

```
try
{
    this.GrdMain.DataSource = null;
    this.order.LineItems.Add(oli);
    this.GrdMain.DataSource = order.LineItems;
    this.FormatGrid();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "btnAddLine_Click");
}
```

Below is code for `FormatGrid()`

```
    private void FormatGrid()
    {
        try
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.GrdMain.Columns.Count; i++)
        {

            if (this.GrdMain.Columns[i].Name.ToUpper() == "ItemCode".ToUpper())
            {
                DataGridViewColumn column1 = this.GrdMain.Columns[i];
                column1.Width = 60;

            }
            else if (this.GrdMain.Columns[i].Name.ToUpper() == "ItemName".ToUpper())
            {
                DataGridViewColumn column1 = this.GrdMain.Columns[i];
                column1.Width = 200;

            }
            else if (this.GrdMain.Columns[i].Name.ToUpper() == "Disposable".ToUpper())
            {
                DataGridViewColumn column1 = this.GrdMain.Columns[i];
                column1.Width = 60;
                column1.HeaderText = "Disposable";


            }
            else if (this.GrdMain.Columns[i].Name.ToUpper() == "Rate".ToUpper())
            {
                DataGridViewColumn column1 = this.GrdMain.Columns[i];
                column1.Width = 70;

            }
            else if (this.GrdMain.Columns[i].Name.ToUpper() == "Qty".ToUpper())
            {
                DataGridViewColumn column1 = this.GrdMain.Columns[i];
                column1.Width = 70;

            }
            else if (this.GrdMain.Columns[i].Name.ToUpper() == "Total".ToUpper())
            {
                DataGridViewColumn column1 = this.GrdMain.Columns[i];
                column1.Width = 70;

            }
            else 
                GrdMain.Columns[i].Visible = false;

        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "FormatGrid");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well what do you do in the `Click` event ?

Comment: may be the order.LineItems having zero content. please put break point in  this.FormatGrid(); and see waht is happening.

Comment: @AkshayJoy i have checked order.LineItems have at least one Item.

Comment: then the Only reson occurs in this.FormatGrid(); this function.  can u please post the Code for method FormatGrid();

Comment: @AkshayJoy , i have added code of FormatGrid ().